# Convert double (0.1) to BigRational and back

Tags: c#, floating-point, bigdecimal

I must be missing something, but when I try to create a [`BigRational`](http://bcl.codeplex.com/releases/view/42782) from `double` value `0.1` it gives me a really long nonsense value.  Converting it back gives `0.0`:

```
double d = 0.1;                      // 0.1
BigRational br = new BigRational(d); // 3602879701896397/71213961919824440...
double d2 = (double)br;              // 0.0
```

What am I missing?  I know 0.1 is not representable exactly in a `System.Double` but surely `BigRational` can approximate it well enough to round-trip it?

Comment: Converting it to a decimal works fine.  They somewhat note that in the documentation.  Why is a double necessary?

Comment: @Jonesy Because I want to use this in code that accepts any finite `double`.  I used 0.1 as an example in the question because that's how I found the problem.

Comment: This was already a known issue about a year ago: http://bcl.codeplex.com/workitem/13051. Check whether the current codebase of BigRational already contains the bug fix. If not, one commenter on the issue provided a fix (i don't use BigRational and i don't know whether the fix proposed by the commenter would actually work...)

Comment: _"That's it"_ -- what's "it"? Are you saying that the bug report led you to a solution? Have you been provided _some_ answer that you feel addresses your question? If there is nothing more to be answered here, please post an answer yourself explaining in what way your question is addressed. If you are still looking for some answer, please edit your question to take into account the bug report and explain clearly what it is you are still waiting for in terms of an answer. On Stack Overflow, questions without answers are not useful.

Answer (score 1):

As @elgonzo explains:

> This was already a known issue about a year ago: [bcl.codeplex.com/workitem/13051](http://bcl.codeplex.com/workitem/13051).

A commenter on the referenced work item uploaded a fix that reads in 0.1 correctly.